Understanding the gap in syntactic analysis

I don't understand the gap assigned to a marker in syntactic analysis. Can you please explain it?
The photograph is from The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p. 1308.
The question should be self-explanatory.  In the photograph, the gap represented by "___" in the syntax tree is an empty category.  Empty categories or null constituents are used in syntax to explain some phenomena or solve some problem.  What is the motivation of using it here?  What coordination-related problem is it trying to solve?

What specifically are you having trouble understanding?

@alphabet Explain why that gap in that image is here. For what should there be that gap?

As I understand this construction, I can't see in the first place how "and" belongs to the second noun phrase since it is a word supposed to show that two noun phrases are being joined in a unique function; since I presume the analysis is the same for "the men and the employers", you can write this now as "the employers and the men" and "and" belongs to the other noun phrase.   If "and" does anything in this construction it has got to be outside of the NP's. Coordinating conjunctions are never mentioned as constituents of NP, in any grammar; it just doesn't make sense.

Also you should explain where the image is from (what book, author, etc), as every linguistics book has a different way of doing it.

@LPH CGEL does, in fact, take the view that "and their employers" is an NP.

So for parallism, both NP in the NP-coordination need a marker. Since the marker for "the men" doesn't actually exist as a word, the GAP is used as a placeholder for it.

@ishtar Great edit! I've also made a few adjustments to the question, clarifying the title and adding the appropriate tags.

It may simplify things a bit to compare their account of this sort of coordination with their account of complement preposing (see p. 1080 and pp. 1372-1382).
Compare these two clauses:

She wrote the other chapters herself.
The other chapters she wrote herself.

The structure of (2), according to CGEL, is:

[ [ The other chapters ] [ she wrote ____ herself ] ]

Essentially, what's happened here (to abuse "process" terminology, see p. 1367) is that the noun phrase "the other chapters" has been moved to prenuclear position in the clause, leaving a gap in the remainder of the clause that we understand as anaphoric to that NP. In other words, the object of wrote is the gap, not the noun phrase "the other chapters"--but we understand that gap as anaphoric to the noun phrase, giving the sentence ultimately the same interpretation as (1), except for the difference in information packaging.
Returning to your example, let's consider these two prepositional phrases:

to both the men and their employers
both to the men and their employers

According to CGEL, the structure of (4) is:

[ [ both ] [to ___ the men  and their employers ] ]

Again, what's happened here is that a constituent--here the marker "both"--has been shifted to prenuclear position--this time in a prepositional phrase rather than a clause. Again, this leaves a gap in the remainder of the prepositional phrase--a gap where the marker of coordination used to be--but we understand that gap as anaphoric to the marker both, explaining why (4) and (3) have the same meaning.
This analysis is important because it gives a reasonably simple explanation of how a marker of coordination can occur outside of the coordination itself. This isn't the only case in which preposing occurs within a prepositional phrase; another example is the use of "Incredible [ though it seems ___ ]" to mean "Though it seems incredible" (p. 633). But it is a rather unique one.

[ [ The other chapters ] [ she wrote ____ herself ] ] This is interesting. "Herself" is an adverbial objective. The gap is filled by "by", creating an adverbial prepositional phrase.

@Greybeard No, there's no implicit or explicit "by" there. The gap corresponds to "the other chapters."
